# How to make a PostGIS LINESTRING with only one initial point

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, postgis-2.0, linestring

I have a service that will be sending GPS coordinates as it moves, and these will be added to my PostgreSQL / PostGIS database.

Right now, created a table with one column that is a `Geometry("LINESTRING")` type.
However, it seems that in order to make a LINESTRING, you need at least two points.

But, I will only be receiving one point at a time. So initially when the service starts sending me location data, it only has one location to send. I will have to wait for the second location submission in order to have at least two points.

What is the recommended procedure to follow in this case for the initial case when I only have one point so far?

Comment: Why don't you store points and then create linestring from them using `ST_MakeLine` instead?

Comment: How are you saying to store the points though? Are you saying store just one point initially, and then once I get a second point, then call `ST_MakeLine` on it, and then call `ST_AddPoint` thereafter, OR are you saying I can somehow store multiple lines in a single db row, and then later call `ST_MakeLine`?